# TCP and UDP Performance

Tags: robotframework

is there anyway to test the performance of UDP and TCP connection using robot framework with the external library Rammbock, according to the documentation i don't see how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can see https://github.com/robotframework/Rammbock/

```
Example:
   Start server
   Start UDP server    127.0.0.1   8282    protocol=GTPV2
   Start client
   Start UDP client    protocol=GTPV2
   Connect             127.0.0.1   8282
```

Comment: i have seen that, and it doesnt answer my question